# PendingIntent launches different activity of the app package

Tags: android, android-activity, android-pendingintent

I'm developing notifications in my app, and I'm having some issue with the pending intent that is driving me crazy.

**Normal flow**: My app has the launcher activity (Activity A, singleTop) which shows a Splash and then launches Activity B (singleTop too).

**Notification:**
When app is in background, I show a notification on the notification bar, which opens the launcher activity of my app when clicked, through a PendingIntent. This PendingIntent addresses to Activity A (singleTop). But in this scenario, instead of open Activity A, it brings to foreground the Activity B, but without calling onNewIntent() (onResume() is being called instead), so I can't retrieve the extras of the notification Intent and show the information, because this Activity B.getIntent() retrieves the old intent which opened the activity the first time.

Can any of you bring me some light on this issue, please?

This is how I set up the PendingIntent:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra(StaticResources.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TYPE, "Notification");
notificationIntent.putExtra(StaticResources.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE, "Message");
notificationIntent.putExtra(StaticResources.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TITLE, "title");

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

**Edited:**
Following the answer given by @Woodi_333, the code for creating the pending intent is as follow.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra(StaticResources.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TYPE, "Notification");
notificationIntent.putExtra(StaticResources.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE, "Message");
notificationIntent.putExtra(StaticResources.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TITLE, "title");

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: Why should it call onnewIntent? You activity has been destroyed as you said app is in background. So clicking on notification will launch new activity.

Comment: SplashActivity.class  -> change this to your navigate activity where you want to go on notification click.

Comment: @PankajKumar I think it should call onNewIntent, because activity is on background, not destroyed. So, as I'm launching a new intent through the PendingIntent, it should call it as it's said on the documentation. However, I can be understanding something wrong.

Comment: @SurenderKumar I have to navigate to SplashActivity, because I need to perform some actions before, and if the app is not in background, it should start the app in the correct order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some code would help but I can take a guess at what is causing this.

So it sounds like the Activity Stack before clicking the `PendingIntent` is A,B. When opening the `PendingIntent`, it closes B because of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` but leaves activity A alone so it remains running.
So onNewIntent won't run because A is still running, and the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag won't cause it to run as when the intent is fired, it is not on the top of the history stack.

You might want to combine it with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` as suggested in [Documentation for FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

I'd also recommend looking at the flags you defined in the manifest to see if they are interfering with the flags of the Pending Intent, or add them to the activities so every time you launch them, they are obeying the same rules.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't provide more code, but it's essentially the PendingIntent creation what is in concern. I'll give it a try with the flags you suggested and I'll tell. Thanks!

Comment: The combinations of flags you suggested is what finally get me to achieve the results I expected. Using **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** in combination with **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** when creating the PendingIntent, always creates a new instance of the activity or brings it to foreground calling the onNewIntent method. For those with the same problem, note that both Activity A **and** Activity B are in the **launchMode="singleTop"**